# Excel - Generate text files with files names and text in two colums

Tags: excel, text, vba

I need to create text files from excel rows. 
The first column will contain the files names.
Each line of the second column will contain the text of the file which name is on the same column.
Each file should be created in the same folder (folder can exists before it is not a problem).
Is it possible and how can I do this?
Thank you,
Liz

Comment: show the code you have tried?

Comment: Anything is possible - but you have to put in some efforts. Show us something that you have coded so that we can help.

Comment: There are already a lot of posts on this subject on SO site.  Look for TextStreams.

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image: pic]

Try the following:

```
Sub MakeFiles()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, st As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Close #1
        st = Cells(i, 1).Text
        Open st For Output As #1
        Print #1, Cells(i, 2).Text
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```